# Increasing understanding of validating a string with PHP string functions

Tags: php

I've just started attempts to validate data in PHP and I'm trying to understand this concept better. I was expecting the string passed as an argument to the `$data` parameter for the `test_input()` function to be formatted by the following PHP functions.

1. `trim()` to remove white space from the end of the string
2. `stripslashes()` to return a string with backslashes stripped off
3. `htmlspecialchars()` to convert special characters to HTML entities

The issue is that the string that I am echoing at the end of the function is not being formatted in the way I desire at all. In fact it looks exactly the same when I run this code on my server - no white space removed, the backslash is not stripped and no special characters converted to HTML entities.

My question is have I gone about this in the wrong approach? Should I be creating the variable called `$santised_input` on 3 separate lines with each of the functions `trim()`, `stripslashes()` and `htmlspecialchars()`?

By my understanding surely I am overwriting the value of the `$santised_input` variable each time I recreate it on a new line of code. Therefore the `trim()` and `stripslashes()` string functions will never be executed.

What I am trying to achieve is using the `"$santised_input"` variable to run all of these PHP string functions when the `$data` argument is passed to my `test_input()` function. In other words can these string functions be chained together so that I only need to create `$santised_input` once?

```
<?php

function test_input($data) {
   $santised_input = trim($data);
   $santised_input = stripslashes($data);
   $santised_input = htmlspecialchars($data);
   echo $santised_input;
}

test_input("%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('hacked')%3C/script%3E\     ");

//Does not output desired result "&quot;&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert('hacked')&lt;/script&gt;"

?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're performing each of the string functions on the original `$data` variable, and overwriting the value of `$santised_input` each time. The output will be no different from simply running the last string function and neither of the first two.

To solve, perform the latter functions on the `$santised_input` variable;

```
function test_input($data) {
   $santised_input = trim($data);
   $santised_input = stripslashes($santised_input);
   $santised_input = htmlspecialchars($santised_input);
   echo $santised_input;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for clearing this up. Please can I ask one final thing? I know now that I was overwriting the value of $santised_input with $data. In the example you have posted we are using $santised_input instead of $number because this variable can store the output and then build on it each time?

Comment: Yeah, the output of the previous function is re-used in the next function each time to get the final result =]

Comment: Thanks again, you've really helped me today.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Sorry, misread the question. You actually can do:

`$sanitised_input = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($data)));`

and that should do the trick, i think.

Answer (score 0):

I never trust in this functions, I'd do with regex using preg_replace.

http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

You should also be aware of the [filtering functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php) added in PHP 5. `filter_var`

Strings can be sanitized as follows

```
$sanitised = filter_var($data, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

There are various options you can use for sanitizing it, for example

```
$sanitised = filter_var($data, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
```

These functions are particularly useful for validating and sanitizing URLs and emails via `FILTER_SANITIZE_URL` and `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL`